# Download HP Power Protector for ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi

The HP [PowerProtector user guide](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.BINARYPORTLET/public/kb/docDisplay/resource.process/?javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.rid_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=docDisplayResURL&javax.portlet.rst_ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01=wsrp-resourceState=docId%253Demr_na-c02881291-7%257CdocLocale%253Den_US&javax.portlet.tpst=ba847bafb2a2d782fcbb0710b053ce01_ws_BI&ac.admitted=1383798904207.876444892.492883150) states that to install the HP PowerProtector client on an ESXi Host:

> Download the latest version of HPPP from the HP website (http://www.hp.com/go/rackandpower).
>   The ESXi Server is automatically detected, and a shutdown command script is generated.

However in typical HP fashion, after clicking through no less than 6 different links to get to the downloads page, I am presented with:

http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/power-protection/software/power-protector/pp-dl.html

> - HP Power Protector (HPPP) - Windows
> - HP Power Protector (HPPP) - Linux x86
> - HP Power Protector (HPPP) - Linux x64
> - HP Power Protector (HPPP) - Linux IA64
> - HP Power Protector (HPPP) - HPUX

The Linux packages contain an RPM and in no way resemble what is in the HP documentation. None of these are labelled for ESXi. Does anyone know where or how to get the HP Power Protector ESXi client installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with [APC Powerchute UPS software](http://www.apc.com/products/family/?id=125), you're not supposed to install UPS management agents directly on an ESXi host. I still think VMware should build something like this into the ESXi distribution.

In practice, my small and large VMware environments do not have any provisions for graceful UPS-led shutdown. There's too much to coordinate (SAN, networking, etc.) and bigger installations have facility-level UPS and generator. Smaller sites just deal with the risk.

Anywho, for your situation, you'll need to make use of the [VMware Management Assistant](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vima/) (vMA) virtual machine appliance. This appliance sits in your virtual infrastructure and can be used to execute scripts on your hosts.

From there, see [**HP's documentation here**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState=docId%253Demr_na-c03600516-5%257CdocLocale%253Den%257CcalledBy%253DSearch_Result&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) about installing the HPPP Linux RPM onto the vMA appliance and modify the execute bit on the shutdown script located at: `/usr/local/HP/PowerProtector/bin/virt_tools/shtdownESXi.pl`

The script has the typical remote execution parameters and will need to be modified to taste:

> perl /usr/local/HP/PowerProtector/bin/virt_tools/shtdownESXi.pl
>   --server ip_address --username root --password rootpassword

Comment: I thought it was odd for HP to be asking me to install an agent on the box itself. They don't mention in their documentation to do this on the vMA (or I didn't see it). Probably should have figured that out myself though.